# How to add a new unordered (bulleted) list to this galley?

Tags: html, css, gallery, bulletedlist

I´m trying to use Cross Browser Multi-Page Photograph Gallery, but I have encountered a problem. It should be easy, but I don´t knw why it doesn't work properly.

Following is HTML code:

```
<div class="photo">    
<ul class="topic">
    <li><a class="set" href="#Portraits">Portraits<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="lbox/portrait1.jpg"><img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/portrait1a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>

    <li class="active"><a class="set" href="#Landscapes">Landscapes<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="lbox/landscape1.jpg"><img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/landscape1a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
    <li><a class="set" href="#Flowers">Flowers<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#flower1"><img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/flower1.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->

    </li>
    <li><a class="set" href="#Trees">Trees<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tree1"><img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/tree1.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
    <li><a class="set" href="#Birds">Birds<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#bird1"><img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/bird1.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
                    </ul>

    <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
    </li>
</ul>
<br class="clear" />
</div>
```

And following is CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">


/* common styling */

a {color:#000;}
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a:visited {color:#000;}

/* slides styling */

.photo {width:635px; text-align:left; position:relative; margin:0 auto;}

.photo ul.topic {padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; width:635px; height:auto; position:relative; z-index:10;}

.photo ul.topic li {display:block; width:125px; height:31px; float:left;}
.photo ul.topic li a.set {display:block; font-size:11px; width:124px; height:30px; text-align:center; line-height:30px; color:#000; text-decoration:none; border:1px solid #fff; border-width:1px 1px 0 0; background:#ccc; font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;}

.photo ul.topic li a ul, 
.photo ul.topic li ul 
{display:none;}

.photo ul.topic li.active a
{color:#000; background:#bbb;}

.photo ul.topic li a:hover,
.photo ul.topic li:hover a
{color:#fff; background:#aaa;}

.photo ul.topic li.active ul
{display:block; position:absolute; left:0; top:31px; list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; height:375px; background:#ddd; width:464px; padding:40px 60px; border:20px solid #bbb; z-index:1;}

.photo ul.topic li a:hover ul, 
.photo ul.topic li:hover ul
{display:block; position:absolute; left:0; top:31px; list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; height:375px; background:#ddd; width:464px; padding:40px 60px; border:20px solid #aaa; z-index:100;}

.photo ul.topic li ul li
{display:inline; width:112px; height:87px; float:left; border:1px solid #fff; margin:1px;}

.photo ul.topic li ul li a
{display:block; width:110px; height:85px; cursor:default; float:left; text-decoration:none; background:#444; border:1px solid #888;}

.photo ul.topic li ul li a img
{display:block; width:100px; height:75px; border:5px solid #eee;}

.photo ul.topic li a:hover ul li a:hover, 
.photo ul.topic li:hover ul li a:hover 
{white-space:normal; position:relative;}

.photo ul.topic li a:hover ul li a:hover img, 
.photo ul.topic li:hover ul li a:hover img 
{position:absolute; left:-50px; top:-32px; width:200px; height:150px; border-color:#fff;}
</style>
```

If I try to add a new categories e.g. Cat, (by copy pasting one of the existing categories), **as the sixth categorie** it won´t be shown (however, it works properly if I do this for 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th list). Apparently number of categories is limited to 5? Anyway, how can I add a new category there?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more `li` but you can't see it ,because it goes down a line, and hidden by the contents of the tab.

[image: screen shot]

```css
/* common styling */

a {
    color: #000;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #000;
}
/* slides styling */

.photo {
    width: 755px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.photo ul.topic {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 755px;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
.photo ul.topic li {
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 31px;
    float: left;
}
.photo ul.topic li a.set {
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 124px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    background: #ccc;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
.photo ul.topic li a ul,
.photo ul.topic li ul {
    display: none;
}
.photo ul.topic li.active a {
    color: #000;
    background: #bbb;
}
.photo ul.topic li a:hover,
.photo ul.topic li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    background: #aaa;
}
.photo ul.topic li.active ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 31px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 375px;
    background: #ddd;
    width: 589px;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    border: 20px solid #bbb;
    z-index: 1;
}
.photo ul.topic li a:hover ul,
.photo ul.topic li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 31px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 375px;
    background: #ddd;
    width: 589px;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    border: 20px solid #aaa;
    z-index: 100;
}
.photo ul.topic li ul li {
    display: inline;
    width: 112px;
    height: 87px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 1px;
}
.photo ul.topic li ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 110px;
    height: 85px;
    cursor: default;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #444;
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
.photo ul.topic li ul li a img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
    border: 5px solid #eee;
}
.photo ul.topic li a:hover ul li a:hover,
.photo ul.topic li:hover ul li a:hover {
    white-space: normal;
    position: relative;
}
.photo ul.topic li a:hover ul li a:hover img,
.photo ul.topic li:hover ul li a:hover img {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: -32px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
     <ul class="topic">
         <li><a class="set" href="#Portraits">Portraits<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
             <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="lbox/portrait1.jpg">
                     <img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/portrait1a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
             </ul>
             <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
         </li>

         <li class="active"><a class="set" href="#Landscapes">Landscapes<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
             <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="lbox/landscape1.jpg">
                     <img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/landscape1a.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
             </ul>
             <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
         </li>
         <li><a class="set" href="#Flowers">Flowers<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
             <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#flower1">
                     <img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/flower1.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
             </ul>
             <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->

         </li>
         <li><a class="set" href="#Trees">Trees<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
             <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#tree1">
                     <img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/tree1.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
             </ul>
             <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
         </li>
         <li><a class="set" href="#Birds">Birds<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
             <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->

             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#bird1">
                     <img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/bird1.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
             </ul>

             <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
         </li>
         <li><a class="set" href="#Birds">Birds<!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
             <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->

             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#bird1">
                     <img src="http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/lbox/bird1.jpg" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
             </ul>

             <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
         </li>
     </ul>
     <br class="clear" />
 </div>
```

**Note**: It's not recommended to set width to all element (tabs container, content wrapper etc). I recommend to set width to the container and the rest of them need to be `width:100%`.

Comment: ok, how to solve this problem? I widened the window, but it didnt help.

Comment: thx. but this image gallery has some other problems. could you please answer this as well?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492749/why-this-image-gallery-exceeds-its-div