# Why this footer is so big?

Tags: html, css, footer

Due to lack of content, my footer has been so big. I was trying to limit the size by adding height:10%  to the CSS, but it doesnt work. How can I limit it .e.g. to 10% of the screen? (I want it to be responsive).

Following is HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper col7">
  <div id="copyright">

  <div class="list-group" style="float:left">


  <a class="list-group-item" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-5x fa-cog-li"></i></a>


</div>  
   <br/> <p>Desgined by </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Following is CSS:

```
div.wrapper{display:block; width:100%; margin:0; text-align:left;}
div.wrapper h1, div.wrapper h2, div.wrapper h3, div.wrapper h4, div.wrapper h5, div.wrapper h6{margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:0 0 8px 0; font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; border-bottom:1px dashed #DDDDDD;}
.col7, .col7 a{color:#CCCCCC; background-color:#2E2E2E;}

#copyright{padding:20px 0;}
#copyright p{display:block; float:right; text-align:right; margin:0; padding:0; width:200px;}
#copyright ul{display:block; float:left; margin:0; padding:0; width:700px;}
#copyright li{display:inline; margin-right:8px; padding-right:10px; border-   right:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
#copyright li.last{margin-right:0; padding-right:0; border-right:none;}
```

And below screenshot shows the problem:
[image]

Comment: if the page height is only 50% of the screen, to reduce the size of the footer you would need to increase the page height. Easiest would be to simply give the main content area a minimum height.

Comment: I´m using a template, but it hasnt made any minimum height for the main content. But I would rather give 70% to main content, rest to footer and header. Anyway, could you please explain how can I do your solution?

Comment: To further elaborate Kevin's comment, your copyright has no background color defined. So what you're seeing is not a huge footer at all, it is a small footer that is at the base of the content and the remaining grey color beneath is just the default body background. It creates the illusion of a large footer but that's technically not what's happening. You would need to do as Kevin suggests. Don't be afraid of javascript. Or you can try adding a min-height:80vh to the upper content

Comment: Dears, thanks but considering that I´m beginner, could you please edit the code for me ?

Comment: You have to first show your full html. We don't know what's above the copyright in this case

Comment: is this helpful?
https://jsfiddle.net/dexoey/hdoy98ag/

Comment: As I´m using a template, there are different code files. I didnt want to make it messy, that´s why uploaded main things. Please advise ahead, if st else is needed.

Comment: Now it works but still there is a problem. If I put it based on percentage (e.g. min-height:60%), it doesnt work. how can I make it responsive and based on percentage?

Answer (score 1):

The ez and faster answer is, add a rule with `min-height` to `#content`. This will pull your footer to the end, and you can do it easily with the `min-height: 50vh;` -for example-.

```
#content{
    min-height: 50vh;
}
```

The value depend of the size that you want for the footer.

Comment: Thx it works but still there is a problem. If I put it based on percentage (e.g. height:60%), it doesnt work. how can I make it responsive and based on percentage?

Comment: Also vh is not recognized. do you mean %, px or what?

Comment: To use % you will need add in the parent the real height, and the parent of the parent.. etc until body so, the better option is use VH. VH is 'virtual Height'. It use the viewport height to calculate and it works fine and is to easy to use.
[Explanation](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have separate footer, its your page size, You are assigning default height which will set to your screen. So, gray color is your body and black color is your content, when there is less amount of content , it shows a bigger footer. Better you set fixed size for content, so if content is less also, the footer size will be same because you have fixed size..

You can do something like this..

```
.col5{color:#CCCCCC; background-color:#000000; border-bottom:1px solid #3B3B3B; height:360px;}
```

In your code, col5 is your wrapper content, so i have set its size to 360px which is a 90% of the size, you can change pixel according to your page size.Which looks like you have set footer to 10%.

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hdoy98ag/1/